# viewcontroller and autolayout rotation issue

Tags: ios, autolayout, viewcontroller

Hi I'm creating my custom viewcontroller hierarchy with the following code. However the autolayout I set in the subview does not seems to work. When I rotate the device, the subview does not stretch to fit the screen.

```
_postVC = [[POSTViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"POSTViewController" bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController:_postVC];
[_postVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[self.mainView addSubview:_postVC.view];
```

`_postVC.view` doesn't stretch to be the same width as `self.mainView` after rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to:

`_postVC.view.frame = self.mainView.bounds // 1
_postVC.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight // 2`

before adding `_postVC.view` as a subview of `self.mainView`.

this way, 1. `_postVC.view` is made to fit `self.mainView`, and 2. `_postVC.view` is configured to resize both vertically and horizontally when `self.mainView` is resized.